# Getting hibernate & ehcache to work with READ_WRITE under Grails on JBoss 4.2.1.GA

Tags: hibernate, grails, jboss, ehcache

I am having a hard time getting the 2nd level cache for hibernate working under Grails.

So I have an application using Grails 1.3.5 which is to be deployed on JBoss 4.2.1.GA.

The choice of app server is not mine and so unfortunately can't be changed/upgraded.

Originally I simply turned on the second level and query cache and set the provider to EhCache.

My queries and entities were then marked up appropriately for caching and I am using the READ_WRITE strategy as they will change over time.

When I deployed the web application to JBoss and started it up this would output the following warning:

*21:24:36,585 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)*

Now this does cause a real problem. I have a data import service which will update pretty much every entity in the system within a single transaction. It can take some time to run but I don't the edits to appear until the process has committed.

Now this works fine when running in development mode (i.e. grails run-app) within tomcat.

However in JBoss the edits are available as soon as they are made in the cache and not when the transaction is committed.

I am assuming this is because of the JTA environment warning shown above.

Now I have tried to resolve this issue by adding the transaction factory class and lookup manager for hibernate.

The relevant snippet from the DataSource.groovy is:

```
hibernate {
    generate_statistics=true
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}

environments {

    ...

    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            username = "root"
            password = "password"
    }
    hibernate {
        transaction.factory_class = "org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"
        transaction.manager_lookup_class = "org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"
    }
}
```

}

The problem is when I now try and deploy the application I get this ClassCastException:

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate cannot be cast to javax.transaction.TransactionManager**
    ... 129 more*

Now I have had a google around and someone suggested that this was caused by included the jta.jar within the web application.

So I removed it using this groovy script in the BuidConfig.groovy file (also deletes logging jars, required to get it working on JBoss):

```
grails.war.resources = {stagingDir ->
    // Extra Libraries to remove
    def toRemove = ["$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar",
    "$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar",
    "$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar",
    "$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/jta.jar"].each {
        delete(file: it)
    }
}
```

However this didn't work and I got exactly the same error.

Any help would be gratefully received. Have spent quite some time googling around with no success. It's not the first bit of pain I have had getting this working on JBoss and am sure it won't be the last!

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem with this, I should have actually deleted the jta-1.1.jar file. That did the trick!